Feign Client with External Rotating Proxy in Spring Boot: Same IP Address for Asynchronous Requests
I have a Spring Boot application where I use a Feign client to make REST API requests through an external rotating proxy service.
The proxy service guarantees that each request will come from a different IP address. (using curl to check the current IP gives different ip every request).
However, when I run an asynchronous method that makes these API requests, all requests end up using the same IP address, rather than rotating as expected.
Here is the asynchronous method that sends a request to check the current IP:
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApiService {

    private final FeignClient feignClient;

    @Async
    public void makeApiCall() {
        Response response = feignClient.checkIp();
        log.info("Proxy IP: {}", response.getIp());
    }
}

For testing, I call this method in a loop:
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    testProxyService.getLocationInfo();
}

In the logs, I see the same IP being used for all requests:
[        Sync-11] k.m.k.client.service.TestProxyService    : Proxy IP: 82.200.168.85
[        Sync-27] k.m.k.client.service.TestProxyService    : Proxy IP: 82.200.168.85
[        Sync-8 ] k.m.k.client.service.TestProxyService    : Proxy IP: 82.200.168.85
[        Sync-10] k.m.k.client.service.TestProxyService    : Proxy IP: 82.200.168.85
...

Method is running N times in parallel.
Here’s my Feign client configuration using OkHttp:
@Bean
public OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT));
    String proxyCredentials = Credentials.basic(PROXY_USERNAME, PROXY_PASSWORD);

    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .proxy(proxy)
            .proxyAuthenticator((route, response) -> response.request().newBuilder()
                    .header("Proxy-Authorization", proxyCredentials)
                    .build())
            .cache(null)
            .dispatcher(new Dispatcher())
            .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Client client() {
    return new feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient(okHttpClient());
}

I also tried setting request headers to avoid reusing connections:
template.header("Connection", "close");
template.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
template.header("Pragma", "no-cache");
template.header("Expires", "0");

Despite these attempts, the same IP address is used for all asynchronous requests.
How can I configure Feign or OkHttp to ensure that each asynchronous request uses a different IP address, as expected with the rotating proxy?

The fact that the calls are made in an Async mode is relevant for the failure of the test? Did you check also if this happens also omitting the Async annotation, or keeping it but waiting some time between different calls? May it be an issue in the proxy?
